# REST/JSON: Should I include a newline after the JSON string?

Tags: web-services, json, rest

If I'm returning ["foo"] from a RESTful web query, Which of these is more proper?  Will pedantic REST parsing die on the newline?

```
["foo"]\n     (with newline, Content-Length=8)
["foo"]       (no newline, Content-Length=7)
```

For easy regression testing I like the form with the newline, but I want to make sure I won't be breaking any application frameworks that might have a more strict view of the REST format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627), **bolded** relevant section for emphasis.

> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six
>     structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>  JSON-text = object / array
> ```
>
> These are the six structural characters:
>
> ```
>  begin-array     = ws %x5B ws  ; [ left square bracket
>
>  begin-object    = ws %x7B ws  ; { left curly bracket
>
>  end-array       = ws %x5D ws  ; ] right square bracket
>
>  end-object      = ws %x7D ws  ; } right curly bracket
>
>  name-separator  = ws %x3A ws  ; : colon
>
>  value-separator = ws %x2C ws  ; , comma
> ```
>
> **Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six
>      structural characters.**

Answer (score 1):

JSON is supposed to be whitespace-insensitive. I suppose technically the spec at JSON.org says "Whitespace can be inserted *between* any pair of tokens," but a parser would have to be very pedantic indeed to complain of whitespace before the first token or after the last.